# How to do high precision float point arithmetics in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In Mma, for example, I want to calculate

```
1.0492843824838929890231*0.2323432432432432^3
```

But it does not show the full precision. I tried `N` or various other functions but none seemed to work. How to achieve this? Many thanks.

Comment: @wallyk Mathematica is a programming environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify numbers using decimal point, it takes them to have `MachinePrecision`, roughly 16 digits, hence the results typically have less than 16 meaningful digits. You can do infinite precision by using rational/algebraic numbers. If you want finite precision that's better than default, specify your numbers like this

```
123.23`100
```

This makes Mathematica interpret the number as having 100 digits of precision. So you can do

```
ans=1.0492843824838929890231`100*0.2323432432432432`100^3
```

Check precision of the final answer using `Precision`

```
Precision[ans]
```

Check `tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers` for more details

Answer (score 1):

You may do:

```
r[x_]:=Rationalize[x,0];

n = r@1.0492843824838929890231 (r@0.2323432432432432)^3
```

Out:

```
228598965838025665886943284771018147212124/17369643723462006556253010609136949809542531
```

And now, for example

```
N[n,100]  

0.01316083216659453615093767083090600540780118249299143245357391544869\
  928014026433963352910151464006549
```

Comment: But what if I really want to get the accurate result for such expression? I know the dumbest way is to do an integer multiplication and then divide by the corresponding powers of 10. Any other convenient way? Many thanks

Comment: @Qiang I find Rationalize the most convenient way, since it manages periodic decimals until the end of the calculation and then (when I want) cut the tail to fit my desired size.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just want to see more of the machine precision result.  These are a few methods.

(1) Put the cursor at the end of the output line, and press Enter (not on the numeric keypad) to copy the output to a new input line, showing all digits.

(2) Use InputForm as in `InputForm[1.0/7]`

(3) Change the setting of `PrintPrecision` using the Options Inspector.